# Are there any alternate ways to apply class weights to tensorflow neural networks?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am currently trying to create a Tensorflow DNN model with a multilabel target variable, and whilst my code hasn't had any problems so far, the imbalanced nature of the dataset that I'm working with has caused a few problems.

As per recommendations in Keras' documentation, I've applied an intial bias to the model. I've also tried to enable the class weight parameter in the model compile function and this is where I'm stuck

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/41448

There seems to be a known bug in this method as seen in this GitHub link, and my attempts at creating a workaround haven't been successful at all. I'd appreciate any advice on creating a workaround because I'm at a loss myself to be honest. Currently running Tensorflow 2.4

Answer (score 1):

You are using a slightly old version of TensorFlow. This worked for me in a multiclass dataset using TensorFlow 2.7 and Keras 2.7:

```py
from sklearn.utils.class_weight import compute_class_weight


class_weights = compute_class_weight(class_weight="balanced", classes=np.unique(y_train),
                                     y=y_train)

model.fit(
    ...
    class_weight=dict(enumerate(class_weights))
)
```

The values of `y_train` must be integers in the range **[0, NUMBER_CLASSES - 1]** for this code to work correctly. You can accomplish this using [LabelEncoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html).

Alternatively, you can use `sample_weight` instead of `class_weight` to accomplish the same thing (in fact, [Keras internally converts `class_weight` to `sample_weight`](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/d8fcb9d4d4dad45080ecfdd575483653028f8eda/keras/engine/data_adapter.py#L1428)). [Here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit) you can find the documentation about these parameters.

Other easy-to-implement and effective methods to combat data imbalance are [oversampling](https://imbalanced-learn.org/stable/references/generated/imblearn.over_sampling.RandomOverSampler.html) and [undersampling](https://imbalanced-learn.org/stable/references/generated/imblearn.under_sampling.RandomUnderSampler.html), which have a similar effect to using `class_weight`. You can use them in case you have problems using `class_weight` or `sample_weight`.